# Bootstrap function for dataframe - passing a function as an argument in R

Tags: r, function, lm, statistics-bootstrap, coefficients

I am trying to create a bootstrap function for my assignment. The requirement is as follows:

> Compute the bootstrap standard error for:   - `mean()` and    -
> `median()` and    - the top quartile and     - `max()` and     - the
> standard deviation of the price. One way to approach this is to define
> a new function for each. Another is to write a `bootstrap_func`
> function that takes an additional argument called `fun`, and then you
> call it `bootstrap_func(B, v, median)` to have the same effect as
> `bootstrap_median`. Implement this function `bootstrap_func`.
> Example call to this function: `bootstrap_func(1000, vienna_data$price, mean)`. Generalize the function further so that the
> second argument ($v$) can be a vector or a dataframe. Therefore, the
> third argument can be a function that takes a vector -- such as `mean`
> -- or a function that takes a dataframe and returns some number -- such as a function that computes a linear model and returns the
> estimate of the linear model. Use this new function to compute
> bootstrap estimators for the standard errors of some linear model
> coefficients on the vienna dataset -- e.g. the effect of stars on
> prices. You have to define and name a function that returns the
> *coefficient* of the right linear model (say `estimate_of_stars_on_prices <- ...`), and pass this function as one
> of the arguments to `bootstrap_func`.

I created the bootstrap function for the vector like this

```
sim <- function(v) {
  sample(v, replace = TRUE)
}
bootstrap_func <- function(B, v, fun) {
  sd(replicate(B, fun(sim(v))))
}
quartile <- function(x) {quantile(x, 0.75)}
```

So I can call an example like this

```
bootstrap_func(100, hotels_vienna$price, mean)
bootstrap_func(100, hotels_vienna$price, quartile)
```

And I think it works fine enough. But I have trouble generalizing it to take also the dataframe and the function that gets the coefficient. My function to get the coefficient is

```
coef <- function(v, y, x) {
  Y <- v[,y]
  X <- v[,x]
  lmm <- lm(Y ~ X, v)
  lmm$coefficients[[2]]
}
coef(hotels_vienna, 2, 12) # this works, col2 = price, col12= distance, result = -22.78177
```

This is my attempt at the generalized code

```
df_bootstrap_func <- function(B, v, fun, ...) {
  new_v <- function(v) {sample(v, replace = TRUE)}
  sd(replicate(B, fun(new_v)))
}
df_bootstrap_func(100, hotels_vienna, coef) 
  # does not work, throw Error in v[, y] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I have tried multiple versions of the df_bootstrap_func but no success, so I think I need a new approach to the coefficient function. I appreciate any input. TIA.